# How can I insert the array value into my table by using Laravel Eloquent ORM?

Tags: mysql, arrays, laravel

Below is the array. I would be like to insert the array into my "sells" table by Laravel eloquent ORM system. but

```
$data = [
                'products' => [
                    'product_id' => ['1', '3', '4'],
                    'quantity' => ['5', '5', '4'],
                    'product_discount' => ['30', '0', '5'],
                    'discount_unit' => ['%', 'tk', '%'],
                ],

                'customer_id' => 1,
                'total_discount' => 50,
                'shiping_charge' => 10,
                'net_payable' => 5000,

                'payments' => [
                    'payment_method' => ['cash', 'card', 'check'],
                    'payment_amount' => ['500', '7000', '400'],
                ],
            ];
```

Here is the Eloquent Code to insert data into sells table.

$sell = new Sell();

```
    $sell->sells_code = 'SCN-' . rand(time(), 1000);

    $sell->sells_date = date('Y-m-d');

    foreach ($data['products']['product_id'] as $value){
        $sell->product_id = $value . ",";
    }



    foreach ($data['products']['quantity'] as $value){
        $sell->product_quantity = $value . ",";
    }

    foreach ($data['products']['product_discount'] as $value){
        $sell->product_discount = $value . ",";
    }

    foreach ($data['products']['discount_unit'] as $value){
        $sell->product_discount_unit = $value . ",";
    }


    $sell->customer_id = $data['customer_id'];
    $sell->company_name = 'Undefined';
    $sell->warehouse_id = 1;
    $sell->total_discount = $data['total_discount'];

    $sell->shipping_address = 'Undefined Address';
    $sell->shipping_charge = 0;
    $sell->net_payable = $data['net_payable'];


    foreach ($data['payments']['payment_method'] as $value){
        $sell->payment_method = $value . ",";
    }

    foreach ($data['payments']['payment_amount'] as $value){
        $sell->payment_amount = $value . ",";
    }


    $sell->payment_date= date('Y-m-d');
    $sell->note = 'Nothing';
    $sell->sells_Status = 'Success';
    $sell->biller = 'Mahady';


    $sell->save();
```

Are you please to share the effective and easiest way to insert array value into a mysql database table?

Comment: You're wanting to concatenate product_id instead of storing it as a proper many-to-many relationship?

Comment: How do you exactly save the data?

Comment: No relationship is needed here. I just want to insert data from the array into my sells table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you are not concatenating product_id, you are actually assigning new value to $sell->product_id on each iteration.

This could help you

```
foreach ($data['products']['product_id'] as $value){
        $sell->product_id .= $value . ",";
}
```

or you can convert this array to json string and then you can store it in you table column

```
$sell->product_id = json_encode($data['products']['product_id'])
```

and on retrieving from db, simple do this, and you will get your array of id's

```
json_decode($sell->product_id)
```

Comment: You'll want `.=` for string concatenation.  `+=` is only for numbers in PHP.

Comment: yeah, sorry just a typo mistake.

Comment: Thank you very much. The json_encode and json_decode is the most perfect and easiest way. It is working.